# Not able to load chinese characters using CString

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using `CString` to load resources from String Table in MFC application, but it does not load any Chinese or Japanese characters (it displays `??` instead of Chinese characters).

**Code Snippet**

```
CString m_resoucestring(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID));
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Is your `CString` a `CStringA`? Or is it a `CStringW`? My guess is that it's a `CStringA`, which represents an ANSI string. Depending on your code page, this may or not be able to represent Chinese and Japanese characters. Use `CStringW` instead, which represents a Unicode string.

Comment: In addition how come you are not using the LoadString method?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your project to **UNICODE character set** in **Project Settings**. After that your `CString` will become `CStringW` automatically which is fully UNICODE compliant. In MBCS mode `CString` is defined as `CStringA` which does support ANSI encoding only.

Comment: `CStringA` uses **ANSI** encoding, not **ASCII**. As you said, it's a multi-byte character string. There are no multi-byte sequences in ASCII.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `CStringW` explicitly if you cannot (or don't want to) rely on project settings.
- You mentioned you *cannot display* - what does it mean? How are you displaying it? `TextOut`, `SetWindowText` ?
- Check in debugger if string object gets it bad, or is it just how you display it?
- Ensure the resource file is saved with proper encoding.